# My Android phone doesn't connect to my server with a HID profile

Tags: bluetooth, android

I've been using my Android phone as a mouse and keyboard to my Ubuntu server (originally running 20.04LTS). At some point, after an update, the app I use no longer worked - it just sits there saying "Connectiing..". I searched but found no solution and then gave up trying but now it's becoming a bit of a pain again so I'm hoping for some insight.

I was hoping updating to 22.04LTS would fix this but it doesn't. Weirdly, the phone does connect (and always did) but not with the necessary HID profile. The phone is a Pixel 6a (but a Pixel 3a had the same problem).

bluetoothctl reports the following (you can see HID is missing):

```
Class: 0x005a020c
Icon: phone
Paired: yes
Trusted: yes
Blocked: no
Connected: no
LegacyPairing: no
UUID: OBEX Object Push          (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: Audio Source              (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: A/V Remote Control        (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: Headset AG                (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: PANU                      (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: NAP                       (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: SIM Access                (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: Message Access Server     (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: PnP Information           (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: Generic Access Profile    (********-****-****-****-************)
UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (********-****-****-****-************)
```

Anyone got any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Upgrading a system with issues will never fix a problem. All that will happen is the issue carries over and may be worse.

Comment: Not sure I agree with that statement. An upgrade broke it, and new drivers in an OS upgrade could fix it. Not in this case though...